# Principle Component Analysis why are we finding the max of the vectors?

Tags: statistics, linear-algebra, data-analysis, statsmodels

I'm attempting to comprehend the PCA but I'm stuck on a specific part. After it being referenced to the Harvard data science course I looked it up here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis
Under details and then just below first component they say "the first loading vector w(1) thus has to satisfy" and I understand why the below line is true?

The arg max where ||w|| = 1 implies were finding the maximum values of the summation when w is a unit vector. But I don't understand why we want that, or how the values are expected to change, if we have a given matrix X. Unless were trying to optimize which weights to dot with each row?

Or do we just do this to get it into Raleigh quotient form, so we can then use the eigenvalues to find the largest eigenvector associated with the matrix? (which is also the largest vector)

and why do we want the largest vector in the first place? In our transformed axis are we just showing the largest variance in each dimension? Wouldn't we want to transform all points and attempt to see some correlation?

Answer (score 0):

In a sense, the eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue is pointing in the direction of the maximum variance. The one with the second largest eigenvalue is pointing in the direction of maximum variance that is left after accounting for the first one. The eigenvector with the second largest eigenvalue will be orthogonal to the one with the largest eigenvalue. Take another look at the Wikipedia article you referenced, and look for the diagram in the upper right. The longer line is for the eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue and it points along the maximum variance in the data. The shorter line is the eigenvector that has the second largest eigenvalue, and it points along the maximum remaining variance, orthogonal to the first line.

Comment: Why does choosing the eigenvector that maximizes the "scores" as they call it, minimize the MSE between the PCs and the data?

Comment: This StackExchange Mathematics entry may address your question. I found it helpful when I was learning about PCA. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23596/why-is-the-eigenvector-of-a-covariance-matrix-equal-to-a-principal-component